# Can access WPF service from localhost but not from different machine in the same domain

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, iis, lan

I have created WCF JSON service and to test it I run it from VS just clicking the run button (using ASP.NET Development Server).

Now I am testing it with [Advanced REST Client](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDcQFjAA&url=https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo&ei=8HrdUtT6KIXYyQGvlIDoAQ&usg=AFQjCNEo489FdO7M0eVz4c9u475vROBbXQ&bvm=bv.59568121,d.aWc) and when I specify something like `http://localhost:56716/MyRestSevice/getoperation` and click send I get just the JSON response I expect. But when I replace `localhost` by the machine's IP address or domain name it does not work. Neither it works when I try something like `http://DevelopmentMachineDomainName:56716/MyRestSevice/getoperation` from another machine in the domain (while `ping DevelopmentMachineDomainName` works). I both cases I get just `0 NO RESPONSE`.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't add an endpoint to your service, so the asp.net server can run the service in local machine but not over the network. you have to add a service endpoint assigned to machine ip and remove security issues from the endpoint, then retest your service.

hope it's helpful